# What does this Microsoft error message mean?

Tags: microsoft-translator

I went to Microsoft developer website and gained a Client ID and Client Secret.

And the following is my source code.  I replaced the last two digits with XX

```
<?php

$ClientID='000000004C12B0XX';
$ClientSecret='yAFqUbNwCqSbs-dQJ5BzF1tWBZggFWXX';

$ClientSecret = urlencode($ClientSecret);
$ClientID = urlencode($ClientID);

// Get a 10-minute access token for Microsoft Translator API.
$url = "https://datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net/v2/OAuth2-13";
$postParams = "grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=$ClientID&client_secret=$ClientSecret&scope=http://api.microsofttranslator.com";

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postParams);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);  

$rsp = curl_exec($ch); 

print $rsp;
?>
```

And the error message I am getting is

```
{
     "error":"invalid_client",

     "error_description":"ACS50012: Authentication failed.

     Trace ID: e2f0bfde-d086-4900-ba1f-a58f02693dac

     Correlation ID: 3750d010-2e9f-45c5-8ba0-f28dfc050909

     Timestamp: 2014-10-20 17:20:26Z"
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I know, it is very old question, but Microsoft has so many ID's.. I also was confused with "invalid_client" error. Microsoft means Client ID is a value, pointed on https://datamarket.azure.com/developer/applications in "Client ID" column. It is an ID you pointed when created your application. Client ID can be any string, e.g. "myid" is a valid Client ID.

> $ClientID='000000004C12B0XX';

Looks like generated value, not user pointed.